# why my CLion on macos debug openjdk source the breakpoints is not step into source

Tags: debugging, clion, java-17

I have import the openjdk source into CLion
when i modify the source and then run the custom build application it works
[run application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nptLI.png)
[debug application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foZcM.png)
but if i debug the source it does not work

[debug application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0e9M.png)

I had changed the compilation database but it does not work
I need to debug the source of JavaMain method if i execute java -version command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current CLion version is 2022.2.5  I changed to CLion with version 2023.2.2 it worked